# 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction Hybrid command error discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this issue where whenever i do
"/purge 10" i get the error "404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction" and it doesnt send the embed, but for some reason it seems to work whenever i do "/purge 1" and sends the embed

Here's my code:

````
@commands.hybrid_command(name = "purge", description = "Purges a specified number of messages")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def purge(self, ctx : commands.Context, amount : int):

    creator = EmbedCreator()
    embed = creator.create(
        title = "Success",
        description = f"```py\nCleared '{amount}' Messages ```", 
        color = discord.Color.green()
        )

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await ctx.reply(embed = embed, delete_after = 10, ephemeral = True) # "delete_after" deletes the embed after a certain time
````

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Does your bot has the [read message history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions.read_message_history) permission in the guild you are trying to use the command? It's needed according to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge). If you can only purge 1 message, that might be what you are missing